# Rails How to save attributes to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to sort data according to certain categories that user chooses. For example, if I have a House model, user can check certain categories (pet, parking, gym, pool), and get a sorted data. 
I'm not sure how to include such categories in the table.

```
class CreateHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :houses do |t|

  t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Is it a good practice to set all those categories as seperate columns with boolean data type? If so, please recommend lines of code to sort the result and display.

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly right. Checkmarks would have a boolean data type, because their value would be either true or false. The code would look like this.

```
class CreateHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :houses do |t|
    t.pet :boolean
    t.parking :boolean
    t.gym :boolean
    t.pool :boolean
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (adding default values will facilitate your tasks later on):

```
class CreateHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :houses do |t|
    t.pet :boolean, default: false
    t.gym :boolean, default: false
    t.price :float
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

When you want to look for all the houses with `pet = true`, you do `House.where(:pet => true).order(:price)`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your list is likely to grow or have user generated categories, you might try tagging instead of adding booleans to the house class.

Check out [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).  If this is too much, you can always write your own with a similar schema: where tags and houses are joined by a join table (house_tags).